# Flutter Error in Just_audio (IOs) after flutter update

Tags: ios, flutter, just-audio

After update the flutter version the plugin Just_audio has stopped working giving me these exceptions (sometimes the code stop before and return less errors):

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: (-1) unknown error
#0      AudioPlayer._load
package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:850
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AudioPlayer._setPlatformActive.setPlatform
package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:1435
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      AudioPlayer.load
package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:780
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      AudioPlayer.setAudioSource
package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:755
<asynchronous suspension>
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method load on channel com.ryanheise.just_audio.methods.26d4c1e0-6fef-4ed1-8917-3ea8d6e473e8)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:313
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannelAudioPlayer.load
package:just_audio_platform_interface/method_channel_just_audio.dart:58
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      AudioPlayer._load
package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:836
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      AudioPlayer.load
package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:780
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      AudioPlayer.setAudioSource
package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:755
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I have tried to clean the project and recover the plugin's versions of the previous code (that was working before the update)

I have tried in a real iPhone, restarted multiple times the computer, the IDE.
I have updated the plugins to the last version.

Can anyone tell me what can be the problem? I am trying to check for other plugins but if the code that was working before is not working now just with the flutter update...

Comment: See: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62006 . Whatever plugin is mentioned in the error message (in this case just_audio) is usually misleading and understanding the cause requires looking over every other plugin you're also using in your app.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was very simple:
I was sending a signed temporal url from my S3 AWS bucket that includes a token in the file name.
It looks like the plugin doesn't like that kind of information in the url.
It doesn't recognise the url as audio I guess.